# Tangent line to a parameterized curve implicitly defined?

Tags: implicit-differentiation, tangent-line, parametrization, implicit-function-theorem, implicit-function

Let

> $F=\sin(xe^y)+e^y\cos z-1$

and

> $G=x^2-e^{xz}-z+1$.

Consider the system

> $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
>  F(x,y,z)=0&  & \\ 
>  G(x,y,z)=0&  & 
> \end{matrix}\right.$$
>
> (i) Prove that the system implicitly defines a *curve* in space, in a neighbourhood of $(0,0,0)$. (ii) Calculate the tangent to the curve at the origin.

Applying two times the implicit function theorem, we end up writing the solutions to the system near $(0,0,0)$ as $(x,α(x),β(x))$, which is a curve with parameter $x$, and the first point (i) is done. We also have $α'$ and $β'$.

But how can we approach the second? I found that the direction of the tangent line in such a case should be parallel to the vector given by the cross product between the gradients of the two functions. Is this true? Why?

If we find the direction of the tangent, can we also find its equation in this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually you can consider the function $$\mathbf f:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^2, \mathbf x\mapsto (F(\mathbf x),G(\mathbf x))$$ and then apply the Implicit function Theorem on $\mathbf f$. You can get an explicit formula for the derivatives of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem

Comment: Thanks @MaximilianJanisch. Actually I have the formulas for the derivatives and have done the first point. What I'm missing is how to use this information to find the line tangent to the curve of the solutions

Comment: The following might be helpful: If you have some interval $I\subset \mathbb R$ and a curve $$\gamma:I\to\mathbb R^n,$$ then you get a tangent vector to $\gamma$ at $x$ simply by $\dot\gamma(x)$. For example, in your case $$\gamma(x)=(x,\alpha(x),\beta(x))$$ so a tangent vector is $$\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right|_{x=0} (x,\alpha(x),\beta(x))=(1,\alpha'(0),\beta'(0))$$

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: alright, sry. Yes, it helps a lot. So we just have the slope, not the full equation, right?

Comment: the tangent line will just be the set of all scalar multiples of that tangent vector. Note that this is a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. So if you want to give the tangent line as an equatoon on the coordinates $(x,y,z)$, you will actually have to give two equations

Comment: And how can I be sure that the tangent line passes through the point?

Comment: I mean, is it enough that we differentiated at 0?

Comment: Well you know that $(0,0,0)$ is the solution we are looking at but $(0,0,0)$ is just $0$ times our vector, so our line definitely passes through that point

Comment: Thanks very much for the help! I was struggling with this question ahaha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102631/discussion-between-shootforthemoon-and-maximilian-janisch).

Comment: The tangent line must perforce lie on each of the tangent planes to the two implicitly-defined surfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part, you may approximate $F=G=0$ near $(0,0,0)$ as follows,

$$F(x, y,z) \approx x+(1+y)-1 = x+y=0$$

$$G(x,y,z)\approx -z =0$$

Their normal vectors at origin are $(1,1,0)$ and $(0,0,-1)$ respectively. Thus, the tangent is $(1,1,0)\times (0,0,-1)=(-1,1,0)$ at the origin.

Comment: Thanks! However, I quite don't get how the tangent is the product between the gradients

Comment: @Shootforthemoon - Visualize that the tangent of their intersection is perpendicular to the normal vectors of both surfaces.

Comment: Thanks, and do we have only the slope of the tangent or also the entire equation?

Comment: @Shootforthemoon - the equation of their intersection near the origin is given by the parametric form $(0,0,0)+t(-1,1,0)$.

Comment: so, in this case the line is $y=-x$, right?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: @Shootforthemoon If you want to be pedantic one can note that we are in $\mathbb R^3$. So the equation $y=-x$ gives you a plane and the two equations $y=-x$ and $z=0$ together give you the line you want

Comment: Thanks @Max precious comment